How to warn a user when a website is opened on a smaller viewport than it was designed for?
I do not want a user to be able to open my website on a mobile device (regardless of it being an iOS or Android device). The website is meant to be viewed only as a desktop application (on laptops, monitors or TVs) due to poor responsiveness on mobile devices. Is there any way I can warn a user (by showing a pop-up) when the website is opened on a mobile device?
Edit: Found a fix that is able to kind of gets the desired results.
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;

    if (width<900 || height<600){
        alert("This website does not support the current viewport.")
    }
    console.log(`The viewport's width is ${width} and the height is ${height}.`);
});


There are a lot of existing questions and answers dealing with redirecting mobile users that you could adopt to reject instead of redirect.

For what it's worth, my Android tablet has a 2560 × 1600 screen. That's way more pixels than a typical 1080p (1920 × 1080) desktop monitor.

I think you may be confusing 'mobile' with 'small viewport'. What is the minimum size of viewport that your site looks OK on? Then do the warning depending on dimensions, not on operating system or type of device (which is notoriously difficult to sense anyway). And remember, on a desktop the user can set a tiny window size if they want.

As usual, you should do feature detection, not make assumptions about devices. Some handheld devices outperform desktops in certain aspects, and they just keep getting better. If it's about screen size, you can use media queries to display a warning below a certain screen size. If it's about performance, you can run a quick benchmark to assess the performance of the device.

@AHaworth yes, you're right. i think the correct word to be used should've been a small viewport and not mobile devices. my apologies

@woka I think some people tend to down-vote questions when they consider the feature being asked for is not useful by itself. Don't get too concerned about that.

I don’t know why the downvotes were cast but it may be because your question lacks evidence of any research or trials of code. Can you show us what you have tried, also perhaps edit the question to give a more correct title as you otherwise will get misleading answers.

@ÁlvaroGonzález A tablet or phone that has more pixels than most desktop monitors doesn't mean that it's easy to see the same detail. Physical size has a lot to do with it too.

@phuzi But I look at my tablet from 30 cm. Trust me, we have a Windows laptop at home where browsing experience is much worse than in the tablet because much less things fit in the viewport, yet there're sites that redirect me to a mobile version with 1 cm letters.

Lol, that is so true and why detection of mobile vs desktop is not a reliable way of determining a good layout. Sites (and applications) should use responsive layouts that adjust to the available screen real estate. OP's "due to poor responsiveness" is the root of the problem and that (in my opinion) is where they should be focussing their effort and adjusting the experience dependant upon "responsiveness" (whatever that means.)

The questions marked as duplicates aren’t. They are looking at the OS or whether touchscreen, neither of which is relevant here.

Please have a go at coding this - you can find the viewport size thro' JS and make a popup (maybe an alert is what you need in this case?) appear if it's too small.

yes @AHaworth. i kind of understand what approach to take, now i'll try implementing it. thanks for your responses and help!

If you don't know what viewport size is needed to view the website how can you warn the user - ie I don't understand "The problem is that values are hard-coded." What else can be a constraint?

this is what i tested out: for viewports above 900x600 the website looks okay and is use-able. below that is when i want to warn a user. this seems like a good enough fix for now.  was just wondering if the way I have tested this is right?

Yes!
You can detect if the page is opened on mobile with this code what I found. This function returns true is the device is a mobile and false if not.


window.mobileCheck = function() {
    let check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
};



And you can show a pop-up like this:


window.onload = function() {
  if (mobileCheck()) {
    document.getElementById("popup").classList.remove("hidden");
  }
}

window.mobileCheck = function() {
    let check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
};
#popup {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #ffffff88;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

#popup.hidden {
  display: none;
}
<html>
<body>
  The page content goes here.
  <div id="popup" class="hidden">This page can be only viewed on desktop devices</div>
</body>
</html>




While I admire the persistence in rootling out all those operating systems, it's not that helpful to the question as it is now posed - the viewport size is what matters (and they can be a bigger on a modern tablet than than a small laptop).

If you want to detect the viewport size, not the device, you can use 2 css methods using the @media rule (I recommend reading this w3schools page):

If you want to give the minimum width of the page as the value of the max-width



/* Replace the max-width value with the maximum screen width */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #popup {
    display: flex !important;
  }
}

#popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
<html>
<body>
  The page content goes here.
  <div id="popup">This page can be only viewed on desktop devices</div>
</body>
</html>




If you want to detect the screen orientation (portrait/landscape)



    @media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
      #popup {
        display: flex !important;
      }
    }

    #popup {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background: #fff;
      text-align: center;
    }
<html>
    <body>
      The page content goes here.
      <div id="popup">This page can be only viewed on desktop devices</div>
    </body>
    </html>



